# Apache Cassandra: Modelling a small table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

What is the best practice to model a column-family having a limited number of rows ?

For example, I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE product (
    productname text PRIMARY KEY,
    productdescription text,
    updatedts timestamp,
    updateduser text);
```

This table can have a maximum of 100 rows in its lifetime. If I make the *productname* as the partition key, then these 100 rows will lie in different partitions which is inefficient. I want to have the entire data reside in a single partition.

What is the best practice to generally design tables with limited rows?

PS: Assume that the only query that will be run on this table would be:

```
select productname,productdescription,updatedts,updateduser from product;
```

Comment: Its hard to know how to best design your table without knowing your required query patterns.  But I can tell you that putting all of your rows in a single partition is *not* a best practice.

Comment: Updated the query that will be used. I understand that it's not a best practice but I believe in this particular scenario, partitioning a small data would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "I understand that it's not a best practice but I believe in this particular scenario, partitioning a small data would be counter-productive. " lets go down:

You can add constant value as primary key, for example put tablename alwayse as "product".

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    tablename text,
    productname text,
    productdescription text,
    updatedts timestamp,
    updateduser text,
    PRIMARY KEY(tablename, productname));
```

More of then, as number of columns is not a problem for the cassandra, as you can "press" such "small" tables in one big table (you need to have only one primary key in each and the type must be the same):

Imagine you have 3 "small" table:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    productname text PRIMARY KEY,
    productdescription text,
    updatedts timestamp,
    updateduser text);


CREATE TABLE hellokitty (
    kittyname text PRIMARY KEY,
    age int,
    owner text);


CREATE TABLE pandarianians (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    pandariantime timestamp,
    age int);
```

Then you can put all 3 in to one where each table would be in one partition:

```
CREATE TABLE lifeislife(
    tablename text, 
    tablekey text,
    updatedts timestamp,
    updateduser text,
    age int,
    owner text,
    pandariantime timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (tablename, tablekey)
)
```

Your select would be:

```
select tablekey,productdescription,updatedts,updateduser from lifeislife where tablename="product";
```